# Can you bind to a dependency property of a custom behavior?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I created a custom behavior that exposes some custom dependency properties whose values change based on AssociatedObject.  I am using these properties for binding in other objects.  Conceptually, think of it like this:

At runtime, the value of the dep prop doesn't reflect in the binding.  Debugging it, I see (certain identifiers changed to protect the innocent!):

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CustomProp' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=82768885)'. BindingExpression:Path=CustomProp; DataItem='String' (HashCode=82768885); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'ToolTip' (type 'Double')

Why is it saying "object" and "string"?  In actual fact, the DP is of type Point (so the binding is to CustomProp.X).  It's like the Behavior looks like a string, or the property type appears to be a string to the binding engine.

1) Is my scenario even possible (binding to a property on a behavior)?
2) Is my syntax right?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh!  I had bad XAML.  I was referencing the behavior using "Source" instead of "ElementName."  Dumb user error!

It turns out that binding to a property of a behavior from another control is just fine.